# Error in onPause and onResume method restoring the user last state

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Am tring to restore the the last page of user before webview app close o paused. But am getting error in `onPause` and `onResume` method, i don't know how to fixe the error `cannot resolve symbol context | cannot resolve method put`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
// cannot resolve symbol context
// cannot resolve method put
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.put("lastUrl", exfilevbrowser.getUrl());
    edit.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
 // cannot resolve symbol context
    if(exfilevbrowser != null) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String s = prefs.getString("lastUrl","");
        if(!s.equals("")) {
            appLoadUrl(s, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inside an activity, directly use `getSharedPreferences()` instead of `context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences()`

If you are inside fragment, use `getContext().getSharedPreferences()`

Then use `edit.putString()` instead of `edit.put()`

Comment: I did this `SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);` and no error except the `put`

Comment: Use `putString`